# How to add x64 to target list in Configuration Manager!

Tags: visual-studio-2008

In Vs2008 I would like to select x64 as my target but in configuration manager I only have "Any CPU" listed?  I have messed around with "new" etc but not sure what to do really.

I am on a 64-bit windows home premium.

Thanks
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the configuration manager active Solution Platform drop down menu choose new and then Type or select the new platform, you can find {Itanium,x64,x86}, choose x64.

Comment: Thanks, should I copy the settings from Any CPU or use empty?